# Three conditional formulas with text?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm a new user and am trying to figure out the formula below.

If cell G4 is between 80%-100%, then I want cell I5 to say "regular," if cell G4 is between 40%-79%, then I want cell I5 to say "resource," if cell G4 is between 0%-39%, then I want cell I5 to say "separate."

This is for a special education project.  Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a table on a new tab - first column is Amount, second column is result. First column values are 80, 40, 0. Second column values are Regular, Resource, Separate. Call it ActionLookupTable

Your formula you want is

```
=vlookup(G4,ActionLookupTable,1)
```

This should work, but I might have one or two details backwards.

You could also handle this with nested if's-

```
=if(G4>=80,"Regular",if(G4>=40,"Resource","Separate"))
```

Comment: Not sure why this was voted down either, maybe for the suggestion to create a lookup table (WAY more effort than necessary).  
The 2nd formula does the job simply and efficiently. Should be G4>=40, tho.

Comment: The lookup table has a natural extension into grades, which is a common in education. A vlookup table is arguably more appropriate in those conditions. Plus it offers more solutions to the problem

Answer (score 0):

Put the following formula into I5 cell:

`=IF(AND(G4>=80;G4<=100);"regular";IF(AND(G4>=40;G4<80);"resource";"separate"))`

Comment: Can I at least know why i was down voted? What is wrong with the formula?

Comment: Not sure, but maybe over-complicated? See Selkie's 2nd formula.

Comment: No idea, this thread seems to be downvotes away

Comment: If the formulas (yours and mine) are wrong, I would at least expect the mistakes to be pointed out, so that we can also learn from our mistakes.

Comment: @Reddy, the issue with your formula is that the AND() functions are not necessary.  Two nested IF()'s are sufficient to handle the three conditions.  Selkie's downvote is harder to explain.  Maybe it's a reflex reaction from someone burnt out from reading the seemingly endless responses to questions that weren't asked. One name in particular comes to mind.  I feel for you guys. ;-)

Comment: I understand that my AND() functions were not necessary. It was to help the author see the limit he/she stated in the requirements because he/she is a new user. Yes downvoting @Selkie is really hard to understand. We will be fine.

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio, nothing is WRONG with you Formula. I do feel LOGICALLY it's closer to the SOLUTION since, OP has mentioned the DATA RAGE to evaluate. It's believed that, NOTHING would happen if the VALUE is MORE than 100.

Comment: @RajeshS I know. That why I wanted/still want for people to at least explain when they down vote an answer. Maybe I should ask about moderators if the site allows that.

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio, welcome to Super User.  Consider yourself initiated.  :-)  Just a guess at why the downvote: it looks like you posted this after Selkie's answer.  The voter probably considered it not as good an answer (unnecessarily more complicated), so it didn't seem to add value.  But it could be because [Tom Post lost his keys](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/215397/269940).  But yes, voting doesn't require stating a reason.

Comment: @fixer1234 :-) He/she also downvoted Selkie that day. :-)